# Activator.CreateInstance to be stored in a Dictionary

Tags: .net

I have a defined a dictionary and when try to store the Activator.CreateInstance, its says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> AssemblyInstances { get; set; }
var typeA = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath).GetTypes()[0];
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeA) as ISomeInterface;
AssemblyInstances.Add("Implementation", instance);
```

Any ideas how can I cache the instances for later use.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never instantiate your Dictionary

I can't know what your "implementation" is but here just assign a new instance of the dictionary and you are good to go

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> AssemblyInstances { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```